# DataGridView don't show data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

So I'm having a noobish problem.

I've done it a lot of times and I don't know what's happening.
There's a SQL query which search for certain rows in the database with null.

```
 Dim productionTable As New DataTable

 Dim findNULLrows As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Index, Product," & _ 
                        " Qnt, Client FROM ProdcutionRegistry WHERE ProductionDate" & _ 
                        " IS NULL", productionDatabase)
    productionDatabase.Open()
    findNULLrows.Fill(productionTable)
    productionDatabase.Close()

    PCPE.DataGridView2.DataSource = Nothing
    PCPE.DataGridView2.DataSource = productionTable
```

After that my datagridview is still clear/empty...

And if I try to show every item in the message box like this:

```
 for i = 0 to productionTable.rows.count-1
     msgbox(productionTable.row(i).item(0))
    next i
```

I can see all the selected index, so my SQL is query is right.
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, i just can't show the itens on the datagridview.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guesses are:

- All columns are being hidden somewhere. I would check for DataGridView2.Columns.Count and debug from there.
- You have multiple grids and the one you're setting isn't the one you expect.
- The data is somehow incorrect.

I thought maybe setting the DataSource to null first was causing a problem, but the following works, so I don't think that is the issue:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim dc1 As New DataColumn("ID")
Dim dc2 As New DataColumn("Name")
Dim dc3 As New DataColumn("Type")
Dim dc4 As New DataColumn("Description")

dt.Columns.Add(dc1)
dt.Columns.Add(dc2)
dt.Columns.Add(dc3)
dt.Columns.Add(dc4)

For x As Integer = 0 To 9
    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

    newRow("ID") = 1000 + x
    newRow("Name") = "Item 00" & x.ToString()
    newRow("Type") = "Test Items"
    newRow("Description") = "Random Test Item 00" & x.ToString()

    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
Next

Grid.DataSource = dt
Grid.DataSource = Nothing
Grid.DataSource = dt
```